# Squeak AFTER Carpet install

Tags: subfloor, carpet, plywood, squeak

We just had new carpet installed. My once quiet floor
now squeaks all over. Prior to our last carpet install we'd screwed everything down and it was perfect.
The only thing I can think is that they removed the prior screws for some reason. Otherwise is there anything they could've done during install to damage the plywood undernearth to make them squeak so much? It did sound like they were rolling bowling balls during install.

Comment: What age is the home? Did you replace the padding as well? Did they or you vacuum? Overall, while it wouldn't have crossed my mind either, the broken down dirt was a damper in some areas. No I would not expect them to have removed any nails or screws from the main flooring area, but if you didn't have them seated, it could have exacerbated the issue. Not to mention furniture was moved in and out. All weight was taken off the wood, so it was allowed to shift. Not out of the realm of possibilities